# ng-view animations transitions in angular

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have a wrap, like a console, and inside it i have another div for the background image and the ng-view of angular like this:

```
< id="wrap">
            < class="introPage">
                < ng-view class='mainView'> </div>
            <end of class>          
        </endofid>
```

Im using animate.js library, which gives me this smooth bounceInLeft which occurs in one second:

```
.mainView.ng-enter {
    animation: bounceInLeft 1s;
    -webkit-animation: bounceInLeft 1s;
}
.mainView.ng-leave {
    animation: bounceOutRight 1s;
    -webkit-animation: bounceOutRight 1s;
}
```

I have a slight problem with the transition itself, the current page bounces off and it seems the second one is bouncing in under it, and once the previous page goes off entirely, the current one just pops up and it's really not the behaviour i expected, what is the cause of this?

For those who don't understand what i mean, it's like when i have 2 divs in a container with a width of 1000px, the left div is width 500px and when the right div is 501px it goes under the left div...

Here is the example page:

http://single.org.il/#/intro

when you click a gender and press go, there is a bounceoutright, and the bounceinleft occurs at the same time, please just see when you remove the overflow-hidden in the #wrap id, the bounceinleft is just beneath the the current page...

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a JSFiddle?

Comment: solved! all i had to do is to put position:absolute in mainView class...facepalmed!